# Face Detection - Filter overlapping windows

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, overlap, face-detection

I am writing face detection algorithm, and now I have much windows detected that overlapping.
I consider that windows are overlapping if `center(windowA) in windowB or center(windowB) in windowA`.

My algorithm was:

```
resultList <- empty list
for each windowA detected
    handled <- False
    for each windowB in resultList
        if windowA and windowB are overlapping
            keep the window with bigger value
            handled <- True
            brick inner loop
    if not handled
        append windowA to resultList
```

But some overlapping windows remain. So, I extended it to:

```
resultList <- empty list
for each windowA detected
    handled <- False
    for each windowB in resultList
        if windowA and windowB are overlapping
            keep the window with bigger value
            handled <- True
            break inner loop
    if not handled
        append windowA to resultList
    for each windowB in resultList, starting from after windowA
        if windowA and windowB are overlapping
            if windowA has bigger value
                remove windowB
            else
                remove windowA and break
```

It's much better, but a few overlapping windows are remain.
Is there a known algorithm that do it fast and good? (The trivial O(n^2) solution is a bit slow)
Or there is another way I can improve my algorithm to work perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was, but with this new code it works as well:

```
result_list = empty list
for each windowA detected
    found_better = False
    for each windowB in result_list
        if windowA and windowB are overlap
            if windowA is better
                remove windowB from result_list
            else (so, windowB is better)
                found_better = True
                break inner loop
    if not found_better
        append windowA to result_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm will still not do.

Consider the case in which the first three rectangles you considered are positioned as drawn on the picture below:

[image]

Note that the three centers of the rectangles are outside the other rectangles, so the first three do not overlap.

Now imagine that a fourth really big rectangle comes. Its center being in the blue rectangle and its value being really big. Then the right thing would have been to remove all the initial three rectangles, but you would not.

As for fast way to solve your problem:

- First sort all the rectangles according to their values (descending), so that you would never want to place a rectangle if it overlaps already placed rectangle (note: here I count on all values being distinct, but if this is not true, then you woul have to elaborate on what optimal solution is).
- Now your tasks transforms to: "You iterate all rectangles sequentially and are interested if the new center happens to be inside any placed rectangle or if the rectangle itself covers any center"
- this transforms to two problems:

  - A. whether any of set of points is inside a newly given rectangle
  - B. whether a new point is inside any of given non-intersecting set of rectangles.

***Problem A*** can be optimised if you keep the laready selected centers in two lists of points (each center is stored in both lists). One of the lists is sorted according X-cordinate, the other according Y. they you can, using binary search select the centers with X coordinate between the X coordinate of the rectangle and Y coordinate between the Y coordinates of the rectangle. If the two sets have overlap - then there is a center contained in the rectangle (NOTE: I have said list, when actually it would be more optimal for you to maintain tree sets for the centers).

***Problem B:*** Again solving separately on X and Y coordinate: you are interested to know which rectangles have the X coordinate of the new point between their minimum and maximum X (same for Y coordinate). In case of overlap - there is a rectangle that contains the new point. This task can be optimally solved using adaptation of binary index trees.

Note both my solutions have worse algorithm coplexity than the straight forward approach you propose, but I expect they will be considerable optimisations in all real-life test cases.

Comment: In your example, with my second algorithm, the big rect will replace the first of the small rects, and remove the rest after that. Have I mistake?

Comment: @Dubon Yup, misunderstood my example. Consider those three come in sequence. All of them can be placed as they do not overlap. Now iagine a fourth one (not even drawn) coming and its center being in the blue area, It has to replace all three. However, your algorithm does not support removing more than a single rectangle in one go.

Comment: It's the purpose of the second `for each`.

Comment: @Dubon mhm you are right, i misread your break. You should be good to go, although probably a bit sliw. How many rectangles do you detect on average?

Comment: I think some hundreds

Comment: @Dubon in case of hundreds quadratic solution should work well. Mine suggestions would work better probable for tens of thousands.

Comment: @Boris_Strandjev Why?

Comment: @Dubon considering algorithmic complexity, additional contant factor, CPU power of modern machines and thus resulting time it will take the algorithm to complete on a single input.

Comment: My solution is not really quaradratic. It's size of input multiplied by size of output, that seem to be lower than log(n)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103139/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-dubon).